# Python : Generate a string of bits

Tags: python, join, bit

I am trying to generate a random string of bits using the following code.

```
bitString = []

for i in range(0, 8):
    x = str(random.randint(0, 1))
    bitString.append(x)
    ''.join(bitString)
```

However instead of giving me something like this:

```
10011110
```

I get something that looks like this:

```
['1','0','0','1','1','1','1','0']
```

Can anyone point me in the direction of what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Fixing your code:

```
bitList = []

for i in range(0, 8):
    x = str(random.randint(0, 1))
    bitList.append(x)

bitString = ''.join(bitList)
```

But more Pythonic would be this:

```
>>> from random import choice
>>> ''.join(choice('01') for _ in range(10))
'0011010100'
```

Answer (score 4):

You are joining the results in the loop itself. You can unindent the `join` line, like this

```
import random
bitString = []
for i in range(0, 8):
    x = str(random.randint(0, 1))
    bitString.append(x)
print ''.join(bitString)
```

Or, better, you can use generator expression like this

```
print "".join(str(random.randint(0, 1)) for i in range(8))
```

Answer (score 0):

You could declare bitString as string variable (instead of appending to list and then converting to string):

```
bitString = ""
for i in range(0, 8):
    x = str(random.randint(0, 1))
    bitString += x

print bitString
```

Answer (score 0):

My one-liner would be:

```
>>> import random
>>> print ''.join(random.choice("01") for i in range(8))
11100000
>>>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code is right, but misses 3 "words": **import**, **random** and **print**)

```
import random
bitString = []
for i in range(0, 8):
    x = str(random.randint(0, 1))
    bitString.append(x)
print ''.join(bitString)
```